# Slang terms for unkempt and badly dressed

Tags: single-word-requests, american-english, slang

What are some American slang words for someone who is unkempt and badly dressed?

I'm looking especially for terms that girls use to refer to other girls in their social circles in a mean way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It’s not slang but:  "disheveled"